# How can I do to load all the resources when starting the app?

Tags: java, optimization, resources

Java loads the resources as they are needed. This make my tiny small desktop application to be very slow when opening a window.

How can I do to load all the resources when starting the app? Is something related to classloaders?

EDIT: does [this code](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4831) work if the files are inside a jar?

EDIT2: Note that the aim is not to reduce the startup time, but to reduce the time of new windows opening after the app is started. I want all resources to go to the memory and stay "ready for use", so after loaded the app will run faster the user's commands.

Comment: Did you try connecting with JConsole and see what exactly is going on when you open a window? If it'a a class loading related bottleneck then you'll clearly see it on the '# of classes' graph. Otherwise you can also try changing JVM settings, this can be insufficient memory or '-server' JIT mode as well

Comment: @bobah it happens to all my desktop applications, its not just this one.

Answer (score 2):

> Java loads the resources as they are needed.

Actually, it is more complicated than that.  If you have a class `A` that statically depends on a class `B` that statically depends on a class `C`, then loading `A` will trigger *eager* loading of `B` and `C` and so on.  But some libraries (and I think AWT and Swing do this) internally use the `Class.forName(...)` method to lazily load implementation classes.  This *reduces* the number of classes that are loaded initially, and (ideally) avoids loading code that your application will never use.

> How can I do to load all the resources when starting the app?

I suppose that you could create explicit static dependencies to defeat the laziness above, but that probably won't make your application's initial window appear more quickly.  A better strategy would be to try to use more lazy loading to reduce the amount of code that needs to be loaded to get the initial window visible.  But this needs to be done *judiciously*.  If you lazyily load classes that are needed for the initial window, you may actually make startup slower.

Compiling to native code (using GCJ for example) is another alternative, but this has various downsides; e.g. larger binaries, more native library dependencies, portability issues, (possibly) slower execution speed for a long running application.

Re your EDIT: I think that code will "work", but I don't see how it could possibly speed up your application's startup.

Comment: "A better strategy would be to try to use more lazy loading to reduce the amount of code that needs to be loaded to get the initial window visible". Actually, I don't care about the initial window slow to show, what I care is that after shown, all other windows need to be ready to show in a fast way. I want all resource loaded in memory for fast access when the application is started. (it will not run out of memory, becouse is a small app).

Comment: Have you asked your users?  Is that what they think too?  Anyway - if you think that is the right thing to do, add the static dependencies as I suggested.

Comment: I saw they using it, and it's no problem waiting the app to load. But is a big headache after the app is loaded wait for every click you give.. ;)

Comment: I think i do not understand well.. using the Class.forName() will reduce the number of classes that are loaded initially? Because what I want is to load all classes/resources while showing the splash screen.

Comment: In the first paragraph of my answer I explained how static dependencies cause the classes to be loaded eagerly.  Then wrote *"I suppose that you could create explicit static dependencies to defeat the laziness above ..."*.  Is that clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is harder: The code is initialized if it is used, which can be seen even on the method level. So you have to run it to load it.

The only other possibility is to buy Excelsior Jet, which does the compile step for you (and returns a nice .exe as a side effect).

EDIT: You can reduce your runtime by Class.forName()ing all your classes during startup, and having everything loaded when its needed. Please note that for having everything really fast, the code must have been run, so maybe you can open, but hidden, all windows, the close them, and then really show the main window from which all other windows are opened. Sadly this will make your app startup really slow. But it can even be done in background, while the user decides what to do next.

Comment: is there a way to iterate over all classes without explicit writing their names?

Comment: the aim is not to reduce the startup time, please see my 2nd update

Answer (score 0):

If you mean also other resources than classfiles then you could use the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to delay loading (lazy loading) until you really need the resources.

Comment: I want to do exactly the opposite, load all resources at startup, so they are available in memory for fast access when I need them.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 and had a similar issue with Java Applications Client Side. Anything that extended any Gui (Frame, JFrame, etc...) would start to take over a minute to run and load from only taking a few seconds.

Traced it down to IIS running in the background (after an update?).

Stopping its service from Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features - Turn Windows features on and off.

And now the Java Applications are loading in a couple of seconds again.

Hope other people find this helpful. :-)